# Excel loading in to pandas via the selenium driver.get url (csv)?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, authentication

I have to follow problem, and yes i'm very new to python.. but after reading tons of pages io couldn't find any solution to my specific situation.

- 1: Using Selenium to login to a secure part of the website
- 2: On the secure part of the website I find a specific .csv (link)
- 3: I have a link = [www.test.com/bla/bla/test.csv](http://www.test.com/bla/bla/test.csv)
  if I use driver.get(link) and use the link, the browser downloads the .csv file to my computer.
- 4: I want to load the .csv directly into pandas. But when i use the pd.read_csv(link) i get:
  **HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**
  to my understanding, this is because the URL is behind the secure login and pandas I trying to connect to it on its own.

My question, how can I load the .csv from the driver.get function to pandas.

I want to load the .csv change some formatting and load it to a DB table sow I other options besides pandas are available that work better in this situation I'm all ear.

Comment: Try using this project https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/, it attaches with your driver and will allow you to get the response of the API call

Answer (score 0):

With the https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/ solution i got the fix.

- link = Scraped link ('www.test.com/folder/test.csv') behind the secure login
- r = webdriver.request('GET',link)
- data = r.content
- c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('utf-8')))

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selenium-requests` package and that will do the work for you

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/

```py
# login to website using selenium
link = 'www.example.com/folder/test.csv' # behind the secure login
r = webdriver.request('GET',link)
data = r.content
c = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('utf-8')))
```